# Microsoft BotFramework FormFlow PromptInStart skips to the resume after function

Tags: c#, bots, botframework, formflow

I'm trying to start a FormFlow from a LuisDialog:

```
[LuisIntent("bookConfRoom")]
public async Task BookConferenceRoom(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{
     IDialog<RoomBooking> roomBookingDialog = MakeRootDialog();
     context.Call(roomBookingDialog, RoomBookingComplete);
}
```

`MakeRootDialog()` builds the FormFlow form:

```
internal static IDialog<RoomBooking> MakeRootDialog()
{
     return Chain.From(() => 
        FormDialog.FromForm(RoomBooking.BuildForm, options: FormOptions.PromptInStart));
}
```

And `RoomBooking` looks like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class RoomBooking
{
    public LocationOptions MeetingLocation;
    public DateTime MeetingTime;
    public double NumberOfHours;
    public int NumberOfAttendees;
    public List<AmenitiesOptions> Amenities;

    public static IForm<RoomBooking> BuildForm()
    {
        return new FormBuilder<RoomBooking>().Build();
    }
}
```

When that intent is hit the resume after function `RoomBookingComplete` runs immediately without the FormFlow appearing. However if I remove `FormOptions.PromptInStart` then the FormFlow does run, *but* you have to send another message to the bot before it starts, which is what I thought `PromptInStart` would fix?

I think I'm getting confused with the order of the Dialog stack and/or which dialog context I'm in. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `Chain.From`

```
internal static IDialog<RoomBooking> MakeRootDialog()
{
     return FormDialog.FromForm(RoomBooking.BuildForm, options: FormOptions.PromptInStart));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @EzequielJadib. Unfortunately I still get the same problem even with `Chain.From` removed.

Comment: What version of BotBuilder are u using?

Comment: It is version 3.8.5.0

Comment: Is there any other piece of code missing? do you have a repro sample?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Yes, the repo can be found at: https://github.com/Poc275/Acrobot